# Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 Not booting normal after install

Tags: boot, server

So I've used ubuntu desktop for a bit and decided I wanted to give server a try for web development. My ISP doesn't block incoming port 80 so I'm going to try some hosting of my and a friends content.

The installation goes well, and I get get to the grub boot menu where it says Ubuntu or Advanced Options for Ubuntu. However if I choose Ubuntu, it goes to a black screen and restarts.

If I go to advanced options and choose: Ubutu, with Linux 4.4.0-31-generic, to  displays 2 lines and then crashes. As soon as it displays the initial ramdisk, it crashes.

If I start in safe mode, I can immediately just choose resume normal boot and it loads just fine. Takes me to login, I can log in, I can ping sites, etc.

I'm not really linux server guy, and google hasn't really given me any relevant results.

I should mention, I have done both dpkg and fsck with no change.

Anyone have any idea's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding out it was an issue with the onboard graphics card that was causing issues.

If I started in safemode, and different graphics defaults were used, I was able to log in.